# problem configuring MPI nodes to communicate

Tags: networking, ssh, mpi

I have installed mpich1 and UPC on a machine at a directory /scratch/sharatds (which is mounted on NFS).

However, when I tried running it inititally,  it used to work well on a single machine (lagrid02) .

When I tried including the other machines (lagrid02-09) as well in the loop, it threw error.

```
rm_3521:  p4_error: rm_start: net_conn_to_listener failed: 36394
p0_30647:  p4_error: Child process exited while making connection to remote process on lagrid03: 0
p0_30647: (38.617188) net_send: could not write to fd=4, errno = 32
```

If you have an idea , what could be going wrong, can you suggest me any measures that I could do to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sysadmin question, not a programming question.

Firstly - mpich_1_?  Really? Mpich1 hasn't been updated since 2005; I would strongly suggest using mpich2 instead.   You won't find many people willing to offser help or support with mpich1 problems.

As to the particular error messages across nodes, there are [several reasons](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q%3a_My_MPI_program_aborts_with_an_error_saying_it_cannot_communicate_with_other_processes) why MPI might have trouble communicating between nodes: do you have passwordless ssh setup so you can ssh from lagrid02 to lagrid03?  Are there firewalls on the various machines?>